# Trying to get working a search option in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

First of all, I want to apologize for my previous post because I haven't asked the question properly. I want to say is that I tried everything and cannot make the two functions work together so I can filter by year and text. I am a newbie in JavaScript, I only know a few functions but it's all. So I would be grateful if someone can help me solve this problem. Thank you.

```
<input id="searchTerm" type="text" onkeyup="doSearch()" />

<select id="options">
  <option value="Estilo8" selected>Todos</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2014">2014</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2013">2013</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2012">2012</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2011">2011</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2010">2010</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2009">2009</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2008">2008</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2007">2007</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2006">2006</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2005">2005</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2004">2004</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2003">2003</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2002">2002</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2001">2001</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 2000">2000</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1999">1999</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1998">1998</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1997">1997</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1996">1996</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1995">1995</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1994">1994</option>
  <option value="Estilo8 1993">1993</option>
</select>
```

To call the functions I use this script:

```
function doSearch() {
  var tableReg = document.getElementById('regTable');
  var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase();
  for (var i = 1; i < tableReg.rows.length; i++) {
    var cellsOfRow = tableReg.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    var found = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < cellsOfRow.length && !found; j++) {
      var compareWith = cellsOfRow[j].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
      if (searchText.length == 0 || (compareWith.indexOf(searchText) > -1)) {
        found = true;
      }
    }
    if (found) {
      tableReg.rows[i].style.display = '';
    } else {
      tableReg.rows[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

And I use this code to select the year:

```
//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload = function() {
  var select = document.getElementById("options"),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

  select.addEventListener("change", function() {
    forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("tr"), function(tr) {
      if (tr.className.indexOf(select.value) != -1) {
        tr.style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr.style.display = "none";
      }
    });
  }, false);
} //]]>
```

So I know there is one way so when I select one year, the text I'm searching only in this particular year.
For example, if I'm looking for water and I select 2014, all I want is to search water in 2014 style filtered previously.

Comment: It's the ID of the table, I have something like this table id="regTable"

Comment: What's in the table? If you're wanting help with filtering from a table and a select, we would need the table HTML, too.

Comment: Here is the fiddle!!! http://jsfiddle.net/45GPA/ thank you very much!!!